# Can I carry work laptop to USA as a L2 dependent?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, work

I will be travelling to the USA to visit my spouse and I plan to stay there for a duration of 40 days. Since I am required to check work related emails and login at least once a week, I am required to carry my work laptop.

Are there any documents that I am required carry in order to carry the work laptop?

Comment: why your work laptop? don't you have something like Outlook Web Access to access your work email through a web browser?

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's written on your laptop cover, in big bold letters, that it is a work laptop, it's just a laptop. You are free to take it with you, and unless you are planning to sell it while in the US, no paperwork is required.

If you're asked at the border, of which chances are negligible, why you are carrying it with you, truthfully say that you will be checking emails (no need to specify if they are work-related) and watching funny cat videos.

Comment: So your answer is, in effect, lie.

Comment: No it is not. Do not volunteer information, answer questions as asked.

Comment: Unless, of course, you never watch funny cat videos, in which case you certainly shouldn't say that you would.